# I can't get Month and Day in Date Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, dayofmonth

I am try get month and day but value is different o my text:

```
var fech = new Date("2021-02-28T00:00:00");
document.writeln("Year=" + fech.getFullYear());
document.writeln("Month=" + fech.getMonth());
document.writeln("Day=" + fech.getDay());
```

Result is:

```
Year=2021 Month=1 Day=0
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j0qn2jjr/3/

Comment: 1) Your fiddle doesn't match your code in the post.  The fiddle is getting the day correctly based on what it is being passed 2) Months are zero-indexed. (UPDATE:) 3) As Máté states below, `getDate` gets the date in the month, not `getDay`.

Answer (score 2):

`getDay()` returns the day of the week (Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, etc). What you're probably looking for is `getDate()`.

Also, `getMonth()` returns 0-11 (January is 0, February is 1, etc).

Read up here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

GetMonth() returns the number month, which in this instance in Feb, using a 0 index, Feb would actually be month 1 in this scenario. Use getMonth()+1 if you need to get the numbers.

@Máté Safranka has explained about the day problem too!